# How to call a method everyday

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uilocalnotification, recurrence

Q1: I want to call a method at the beginning of the day (every day), even if the user 
doesn't open the application?

Q2: I want to display a notification within certain time?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

[UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) for you.  Google will turn up many more.

Comment: You are not answering the question. He is asking "call a method on scheduled time even the app is not running", your answer is "Display a message on scheduled time".

Comment: No, the answer is appropriate. Responding to a remote or local notification on iOS can call an arbitrary method on the app as it's moved to the foreground. As a general case, calling a method at a scheduled time on a backgrounded app is not possible.